# How to add "create a new python file" to the registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, python

I have Python 3.2 on a windows 7 operating system. The other day I thought that it would be convenient to add a link to create a new `.py` file in the right hand click "new" menu. I had worked with the registry before and looked up how to add an item to the "new" menu, but when I got to the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` the `.py` extension key was not there. I only know how to add something to the "new" menu using the extension key. I searched the web, but could not come up with any other ways. Python works perfectly fine, and I don't want to mess anything up by adding the extension key. So here are my questions:

Will I mess up python or something else by adding a `.py` key?( I know it is dangerous to work with the registry, that is why I am looking for a safe solution)
If not how can I go about doing this?

OR

Is there a different way to add "create a new python file" to the "new" menu?
If so how can I do it?

OR

If the only way is very complicated should I forget about it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S I originally posted on Stack Overflow that they told me to move it over here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use the "new > text document" context menu item, change the name of the new file and add a `.py` extension.

To extend the explorer, you'll need a [shell extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer#Extensibility).

There is a free software configurable [context menu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contextmenushel/) available. Be careful with windows installers from sourceforge though. Word is that sourceforge now [bundles adware](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/07/17/sourceforges-new-installer-bundles-program-downloads-with-adware/) with them!

**Edit:** Adding a new type to the context menu can indeed be done by [fiddling with the registry](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-remove-items-from-new-menu-in-windows/).

Comment: He’s not asking about creating new context menus, he’s asking about adding an entry to the existing *New→* menu.